# Override [.data.frame to drop unused factor levels by default

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, r-factor

The issue of dropping unused factor levels when subsetting has come up [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/dropping-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r). Common solutions include using character vectors where possible by declaring

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Sometimes, though, ordered factors are necessary for plotting, in which case we can use convenience functions like `droplevels` to create a wrapper for `subset`:

```
subsetDrop <- function(...){droplevels(subset(...))}
```

I realize that `subsetDrop` mostly solves this problem, but there are some situations where subsetting via `[` is more convenient (and less typing!).

My question is how much further, for the sake of convenience, can we push this to be the 'default' behavior of R by overriding `[` for data frames to automatically drop factor levels. For instance, the Hmisc package contains `dropUnusedLevels` which overrides `[.factor` for subsetting a single factor (which is no longer necessary, since the default `[.factor` appears to have a `drop` argument for dropping unused levels). I'm looking for a similar solution that would allow me to subset data frames using `[` but automatically dropping unused factor levels (and of course preserving order in the case of ordered factors).

Comment: Ordered factors are almost never needed to plotting. Changing the order of levels is often at the core of plotting difficulties. Ordering factors is quite different than changing the order of factor levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be really wary of changing the default behavior; you never know when another function you use depends on the usual default behavior.  I'd instead write a similar function to your `subsetDrop` but for `[`, like

```
sel <- function(x, ...) droplevels(x[...])
```

Then

```
> d <- data.frame(a=factor(LETTERS[1:5]), b=factor(letters[1:5]))
> str(d[1:2,])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2
 $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2
> str(sel(d,1:2,))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
 $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
```

If you really want to change the default, you could do something like

```
foo <- `[.data.frame`
`[.data.frame` <- function(...) droplevels(foo(...))
```

but make sure you know how namespaces work as this will work for anything called from the global namespace but the version in the base namespace is unchanged.   Which might be a good thing, but it's something you want to make sure you understand.  After this change the output is as you'd like.

```
> str(d[1:2,])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
 $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks (and +1 for @kohske who got there too)! Should've thought of using essentially the same trick as with subset(). And you're right, better to avoid conflicts...

Answer (score 5):

you can do that work by overwriting the default value of the drop argument like this:

```
formals(`[.factor`)$drop <- TRUE
```

UPDATE

as for data.frame, you can do by:

```
`[.data.frame` <- function(...)droplevels(base::`[.data.frame`(...))
```

actually similar as @Aaron's one.

if you want to cancel this behavior, then:

```
rm(`[.data.frame`)
```

will do that.

```
> d <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=LETTERS[1:10])
> str(d[1:5, ])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
> `[.data.frame` <- function(...)droplevels(base::`[.data.frame`(...))
> str(d[1:5, ])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
> rm(`[.data.frame`)
> str(d[1:5, ])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: That changes the default behavior for subsetting a single factor vector, but (at least when I tried it) has no effect when using `[` on a data frame that contains a factor, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think that changing the default is very dangerous, see my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376934/r-read-rows-with-specific-column-values/6378794#6378794).

Most cases where people are concerned with dropping factor levels you either really don't need to (sumarizing something that you forced to have 1 value is silly) or there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying.  The possible side effects from auto dropping is potentially worse than the couple of keystrokes saved.  Also if you are doing reproducable research then you should not be depending on or even allowing the computer to change data without your specific say so.